# Namespaces of identifiers in C

Tags: c, namespaces, c99

From (6.2.3/1) C99 Standard

> -- the tags of structures, unions, and enumerations (disambiguated by following any* of the keywords struct, union, or enum);
>
> *footnote: There is only one name space for tags even though three are possible.

Now, I know that in C++ we use namespaces to avoid conflicts of entities such as:

```
namespace foo {
     struct bar // ..define bar..
};

namespace foo2 {
     struct bar // ..define bar..
};
```

In C, How do struct, union, enum serve as a namespace and what does the footnote mean that there's only one name space and not three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a separate namespace for the *tags* of structs, unions and enums, so you can have

```
struct foo {
    int bar;
};
double foo;
```

since the namespace of tags is separate from the namespace of identifiers. That there is only one namespace for the tags means that you cannot have

```
struct foo {
    int bar;
};
union foo {
    double baz;
    long quux;
}
```

in the same scope.

Comment: Does having a separate namespace of tags from the namespace of identifier mean that they aren't declared at one namespace e.g. global namespace? How is `struct foo` is really separate from `double foo`? As I recall in C++, it was called Name hiding.

Comment: Namespaces in C are not the same as in C++. If you know Haskell, that's more similar, you have separate namespaces for types, and values there, so you can have both a type `Foo` and a value constructor `Foo` together, like in C you can have a `struct` tagged `foo` and a variable named `foo`. In both cases, the namespaces are global in the sense that you can have only one entity of a kind with the given name (but you can have entities of the same kind with the same name in different scopes).